# Recursive List - Computing the sum of all elements up to and including the last occurrence

Tags: java, recursion

It´s not only a Java question. It is a question of algorithms in general:

The task is to compute the sum of all the elements up to and including the last occurred value "val", which is a parameter in the method.

Method looks like:

int sumLastOcc (Node n, int val)

// n is the node of the list. Starts with the head when the method will be called.

// val is the value up to which the total sum will be formed

Example: 3 5 2 7 5 1 4

Result: 22 for val = 5 (call: sumLastOcc (head, 5))

Result: 0 for val = 9 (call: sumLastOcc (head, 9))

```
public class RecursiveList {
    static Node head;
    static boolean found = false;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        RecursiveList list = new RecursiveList();

        list.addNumber(3);
        list.addNumber(5);
        list.addNumber(2);
        list.addNumber(7);
        list.addNumber(5);
        list.addNumber(1);
        list.addNumber(4);
        list.printList();

        int result = list.sumLastOcc(head, 5);

        System.out.println();
        System.out.println(result);
    }

    private int sumLastOcc(Node n, int val) {
        // CODE TO IMPLEMENT    
        }

        return sum;
    }

    private void addNumber(int number) {
        Node curr = head;
        Node prev = null;

        if (head == null) {
            head = new Node(number, null);
        } else {
            while (curr != null) {
                prev = curr;
                curr = curr.next;
            }

            Node newNode = new Node(number, null);
            prev.next = newNode;
        }
    }

    // inner node class
    private class Node {
        Node next;
        int value;

        Node(int value, Node next) {
            this.value = value;
            this.next = next;
        }
    }

    private void printList() {
        Node curr = head;
        Node prev = null;

        while (curr != null) {
            System.out.print(curr.value + " ");

            prev = curr;
            curr = curr.next;
        }
    }
}
```

It´s okay to use/add any global static variables like:

static boolean found = false;

as already defined.
We should use no loops (for, while, ...) and we should also use no additional method. Just the method "private int sumLastOcc(Node n, int val)" should do that charm.

Comment: I'm not going write code instead of you but general idea is you have two aggregators  `sumUpTo` and `sumAfter`. You iterate over list and accumulate data in `sumAfter`. Once you meet your target value, you add it to `sumAfter`, then accumulate `sumUpTo += sumAfter`, set zero to `sumAfter` and continue iterating. Given that your `sumUpTo` has correct value at any point of time/iteration and you return its value as is when iteration is over

Comment: The task is kinda interesting. Are you sure you must not use any loops? Without loops, you have just two ways - recursive calls (length of an acceptable list is limited by thread stack size) or spanning chain of threads (looks too much for homework). 

Probably 1st way is ok if for homework list length is limited by a relatively small number. 

BTW, your list is Linked not Recursive

Answer (score 0):

I can explain  -
   Traverse the list until the end and keep on adding the values. Also from the match set the flag (found to true) to keep track of deductions until you reach the end or find another match. Reset the counter on finding the match.

In pseudo-code like

```
private int sumLastOcc(Node n, int val) {
   if n.next != null 
     //traverse the list until the end
     //add the value to sum
     sum = sum + n.value

     //keep track of values from the match
     if(found)
     deduct = deduct + n.value;

     //reset the flag when match found
     deduct = 0
     found = true

     //call until reach the end
     sumLastOcc(n.next, val)
   else 
     //add the last node value
     sum = sum + n.value

    //even for the deduct
    if (found) 
     deduct = deduct + n.value;

  //lastly return sum - deduct
  return found?sum - deduct:0
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Thank you guys for the fast and nice respond. I wrote the method similar according to the explanation of Alexander Pavlov. Think this is a very good way:

```
private int sumLastOcc(Node n, int val) {
    int sumUpTo = 0;    
    int sumAfter = 0;                   

    if (n.next != null) {
        sumAfter = sumAfter + n.value + sumLastOcc(n.next, val);

        if (n.value == val) {
            found = true;
        }

        if (found) {
            sumUpTo = sumUpTo + sumAfter;
        }
    } else {
        sumAfter = sumAfter + n.value;

        if (n.value == val) {
            sumUpTo = sumUpTo + sumAfter;
            found = true;
        }
    }

    return sumUpTo;
}
```

So this is solved :-)